# Why people may be born disabled?

Tags: creation, disability

This is a similar question to one that has been deleted a while ago while I was in the process of answering, therefore I am posting this question in the purpose of helping others who may seek the same query!

1. Why is it that some of us are born deaf, blind or with any other disability or developed them through their lifetime?
2. Does this mean that the healthy have an advantage over the sick?
3. Are the sick rewarded for their patience during sickness?

Answer (score 2):

but let me tell you your question and correct me if i am wrong.

1.the science has tell us that a disable baby come from bad nutrient, off course there are some gene that play part on that. but the condition of mother nutrient play the most essential parts. this, i think bring us to another problem which is poverty.
In surrah Al-Isra, we know we cannot choose where we will be born. so no matter what the condition of our life that we face on. it's actually still with in our boundary. you can choose to sad about it or striving for a better life.

2.yes it is, but like everybody else we have problem of our own. when you are suffer still its feels like the worse compared to another person suffering (which is very subjective off course)

3.off course it is but before that, remeber "inna mal a'maluu binnniat"...."every act as based on niat (intention)". if be patience during sickness were considered as Ibadah (good deeds) of course it will be rewarded.

Comment: (1) could be the scientific explanation of *Allah's wish.*

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I would like to make clear before I attempt to answer this question is: There are things that are done by Allah which we may not know the reason why, and this is something that we have to accept, this is derived from the conversation between GOD and Angels:

> (2:30) And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed,
>   I will make upon the earth a successive authority." They said, "Will
>   You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood,
>   while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I
>   know that which you do not know."

Just because God may do things that we may not YET understand, it does not mean that God does things with no purpose:

> “Did you think that We had created you in play (without any purpose),
>   and that you would not be brought back to Us?”
>
> So Exalted be Allaah, the True King: Laa ilaaha illa Huwa (none has
>   the right to be worshipped but He), the Lord of the Supreme Throne!”
>   [al-Mu’minoon 23:115, 116]
>
> “We created not the heavens and the earth and all that is between them
>   for a (mere) play”[al-Anbiya’ 21:16]
>
> We created them not except with truth (i.e. to examine and test those
>   who are obedient and those who are disobedient and then reward the
>   obedient ones and punish the disobedient ones), but most of them know
>   not” [al-Dukhaan 44:38]

We also have to remember that God is just, Satan may be putting the idea into your head that others have an advantage over you, But nay YOU have the advantage over others:

> Aisha (may Allah be pleased with her) reported that the Messenger of
>   Allah (pbuh) said, “For any adversity a Muslim suffers, Allah erases
>   some of his sins, even though it may be no more than a thorn pricking
>   him.” (Related by Al-Bukhari
>
> Another version of this Hadith is also related by Al-Bukhari on the
>   authority of two of the Prophet’s (pbuh) companions, namely, Abu Saeed
>   Al-Khudri and Abu Hurairah who quote him as saying: “Whatever befalls
>   a Muslim of exhaustion, illness, worry, grief, nuisance or trouble,
>   even though it may be no more than a prick of a thorn, earns him
>   forgiveness by Allah of some of his sins.”
>
> Jabir ibn Abdullah narrated that Allah’s Messenger salallahu alayhi
>   wasallam said, “On the Day of Resurrection, when people who have
>   suffered affliction are given their reward, those who are healthy will
>   wish their skins had been cut to pieces with scissors when they were
>   in the world.” (Al-Tirmidhi, 1570)

many more here and here

We also know that each soul can be more capable than another:

> “Allah does not burden a soul beyond that it can bear…” (Qur’an,
>   2:286).

Therefore believe that you are strong enough to handle this and know that you will be rewarded for it!

You have to also bear in mind that this can help you abstain from sin, our tongues, limbs, ears and sights shall shall be used in only what please Allah not the opposite, the following Hadeeth is one of many revealing the consequences of not using such organs correctly:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "He who narrates a dream which he has not seen
>   will be put to trouble to join into a knot two barley seeds which he
>   will not be able to do; and he who seeks to listen to the talk of a
>   people (secretly) will have molten lead poured into his ears on the
>   Day of Resurrection; and he who makes a picture (of people or other
>   creatures with a soul, such as animals and insects) will be (severely
>   punished), and he will be asked to infuse spirit therein, which he
>   will not be able to do."

I am sure that if I was blind and deaf will definitely have earned mush less sins than what I have now!

This might be a test that your going through only god knows why:

> “And certainly, We shall test you with something of fear, hunger, loss
>   of wealth, lives and fruits…” (Qur’an, 2:155)

Do not compare yourself to others in a negative way for example do not say they have wealth and I don't, no matter how much you go through there is always someone who is going through more than you

> On the authority of Abu Huraira (R.A.A.) who said: The Prophet (PBUH),
>   said: "Look upon one who is below you in status. In this way you will
>   not look down upon the grace of that God bestowed upon you." (Bukhari
>   and Muslim)

Be thankful for what you have:

> . . . then when (Sulaiman (Solomon)) saw it placed before him, he
>   said: “This is by the Grace of my Lord to test me whether I am
>   grateful or ungrateful! And whoever is grateful, truly, his gratitude
>   is for (the good of) his own self, and whoever is ungrateful, (he is
>   ungrateful only for the loss of his own self). Certainly! My Lord is
>   Rich (Free of all wants), Bountiful” [An-Naml: 40]
>
> “And (remember) when your Lord proclaimed: ‘If you give thanks (by
>   accepting Faith and worshipping none but Allah), I will give you more
>   (of My Blessings); but if you are thankless, verily, My punishment is
>   indeed severe’” [Ibraaheem 14:7]

May Allah Guide Us all!